# run CakePHP 1.2.9 in PHP Version 5.4.19

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am running CakePHP 1.2.9 on my xampp server 1.8.2 with PHP version 5.4.19.
But I am getting some errors like

```
Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class Object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME\cake\libs\object.php on line 62

Strict Standards: Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\paris-clone\cake\bootstrap.php on line 46
```

I tried to figure this out with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134285/strict-standards-redefining-already-defined-constructor-for-class-object-in-pat), but not succeeded.
please help me with it.
Thanks

Comment: The first means that you already defined someting with the same name. I guess the class `Object`. The second means that you are calling a function which is not static

Comment: I did not do anything I just put the CakePHP downloaded files in htdocs

Comment: You know that 1.2 is outdated?

Comment: I know but its client requirement and he is stick to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 E_STRICT is included in E_ALL. Maybe CakePHP 1.x doesn't know of E_STRICT setting ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Change logging in your application to display only errors:

```
    'level' => E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE,
```

Or set in in php.ini.

You might also want to set level debug to disable error displaying on production mode in the first place. In cakephp 2 it is achieved by setting debug var in core.php:

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```