# How do I avoid " PHP Strict Standards" if I cannot change the version of my PHP (PHP 5)

Tags: php, error-handling, php-5.4

Here are some examples to some of the errors. I heard this is a result of old code in new code, but I can't change my PHP version off the native 5.4 version ispmanager uses because I need Apache. Tried switching version but it messes up my site. Any ideas?

````
PHP Strict Standards:  Redefining already defined constructor for class Object in /var/www/ku/data/www/Public IP/cake/libs/object.php on line 54, referer: http://Public IP/posts/add


PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method Configure::getInstance() should not be called statically in /var/www/ku/data/www/Public IP/cake/bootstrap.php on line 38, referer: http://Public IP/posts/add


PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /var/www/ku/data/www/Public IP/cake/libs/cake_log.php on line 182, referer: http://Public IP/posts/add```
````

Comment: try reading here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134285/strict-standards-redefining-already-defined-constructor-for-class-object-in-pat

Comment: Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134285/strict-standards-redefining-already-defined-constructor-for-class-object-in-pat>

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134285/strict-standards-redefining-already-defined-constructor-for-class-object-in-pat>?

Answer (score 0):

adding this in your PHP code may solve your problem.

```
error_reporting(0);
#this will display no errors.

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
#this will make it just not strict
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Not showing errors doesn't solve the problem, errors still occur. Better fix them, not hide them

Comment: Yeah that looks like it, but I wanna know if these errors are harmful or no?

Comment: @AidanGarcia still using PHP 5.4 is to be considered harmful in itself already, that is out of support and has not received security fixes for ages.

Comment: @AidanGarcia am not sure about the harmfulness. Anyways upgrading the version is always the best practice.

Comment: @NikhilJoy any way to completely get rid of these errors and fix everything? Like I said, I cannot change versions.

Comment: @CBroe I'm using someone else program, not really knowledgeable enough in php.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the php.ini, add/change the following to it:

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT`

If you don't have access to the php.ini, and you run via Apache (you can have .htaccess file in root). Add this to .htaccess:

`php_value error_reporting 30711`

Last option is like mentioned by nikhil.

Comment: Also looking at ispmanager. They advertise, you can run multiple php versions. The best option would be to look into upgrading PHP. Older PHP version can be harmfull by itself.
https://www.ispsystem.com/software/ispmanager/features/php-versions

Comment: I can't switch off the native version, i've tried and my website doesnt work. It has to have Apache PHP mode and nothing else. You can't do it with other versions because they are "alternate."